# Mildness of hypotheses

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation

When formulating a theory, the theory is "stronger" the weaker the assumptions are, for fixed consequences. For example a theory of the form "Continuous $\Rightarrow C_1$" is much stronger than a theory of the form "Differentiable $\Rightarrow C_1$", since "Differentiable $\Rightarrow$ Continuous".

I have come across expressions of the form:

> "If we add the *comperatively mild* condition $H$ then we can be assured that..."

As a concrete example, "Differentiability $\Rightarrow$ Existence of partial derivatives" , to go the other way, Munkres in his "Analysis on Manifolds", states that *we need to add the **comperatively mild** condition that the partials also be continuous.*

My question is this, is there a way to quantify how "mild" a statement is, other than your own personal opinion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not.  You can say condition $X$ is milder than condition $Y$ if $Y$ implies $X$, but if neither implies the other, there is typically no natural objective way to say one is milder than the other.  These phrases are just informal and based on intuition and experience.

Comment: In particular, a hypothesis is likely to be considered "mild" if it is true of many of the examples that are typically considered. Of course, when you are applying theorems from one field to problems in another, you may find that the "mild" hypotheses aren't so mild anymore. For example, the [Zariski topology](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZariskiTopology.html) is relatively "weird" compared to many traditional topological examples.